# Zend_Cache - retrieve expired data?

Tags: web-services, zend-framework, zend-cache

I'm using Zend_Cache to cache data generated from a web service. However, in the event the web service does not respond, I want to display the outdated information and not leave a blank space.

According to the documentation, the answer is to pass the second argument to `Zend_Cache_Core::load()`:

```
@param  boolean $doNotTestCacheValidity If set to true, the cache validity won't be tested
```

However, for every test I've done this always returns `bool(false)` for expired cache content.

Is there a way to force Zend_Cache to return the cached data for a given cache key, even when it has expired?

```php
$cache_key = md5($url);
if ($out = $cache->load($cache_key)) {
  return $out;
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

if ($output) {
  // Process...
  $cn_cache->save($out, $cache_key);
} else {
  // The query has timed out/web service not responded
  // We need to load the outdated cached content... but the following DOES NOT work
  return $cache->load($cache_key, true);

  // var_dump($cache->load($cache_key, true)); # false
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the invalid cache entry is still there, that it has not be "cleaned"? Remember, the default `automatic_cleaning_factor` is 10, meaning a 1-in-10 chance of invalid cache entries being removed on each cache write. Just spitballing...

Comment: @DavidWeinraub I checked the files still existed in the cache directory, however I didn't check if the files had been modified (is there a delete flag set vs removing the file?) and will do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a reliable way to do this other than to have a second cached version of the object that *never* expires. If you set a cache expiration time of X seconds on an object, there's simply no way to guarantee that the object will still be there after X seconds.

Example proposed workaround below...

```
...
$cache_key_forever = sha1($url)
if ($output) {
  // Process...
  $cn_cache->save($out, $cache_key);
  $cn_cache->save($out, $cache_key_forever, array(), null); // The "null" parameter is the important one here: save cache indefinitely
} else {
  // The query has timed out/web service not responded
  // Load the infinitely persisted cache object
  return $cache->load($cache_key_forever);

  // var_dump($cache->load($cache_key, true)); # false
}
```